# Azure Notification Hub Rest API with iOS Swift 401 Error from device

Tags: azure-notificationhub

I'm unable to generate a valid Authentication Token using iOS Swift and keep getting a 401 error when trying to send a push notification directly from a iPhone.

The documentation on Microsoft Azure's website is incomplete and written in Objective C.  After translating to Swift, some parts of it call old functions that have been deprecated.

Comment: Could you paste the code and detailed error message that you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  The Objective C to Swift translator wasn't working as expected so I just coded it in Objective C and everything works, although the documentation on the Azure website needs to be updated to iOS10.